# glossy direct pass (view layer properties)

Tags: materials, render-passes, viewlayers

I am going through a step by step tutorial.
But at a certain stage, my render differs from the scene of the author.
Please help me figure out why my render is partially colored. The author is in black and white.
thank you

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rqueF4I0AO3OX7s8uDdgwg2wzeTR8LY8/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: Is that tutorial available online?  could you add a URL if it's freely available? I suspect that the author has a view setting different than yours.  It looks like your viewport is showing a full render while his is only showing the output for a specific pass.

Comment: Also, I've noticed an error in the compositor node group in your example. You have a loop between the add and alpha over nodes.  That doesn't fix the display but maybe there are other issues?

Comment: thank you!
tutorial URL: https://youtu.be/wlmq6EXzzzw?t=874
14:35

Comment: I think Price was using an early version of 3.0 and his display is showing a bug, or the feature has since changed.  If you go on with the tutorial do you get the effect you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some metallic value in Icing and Sprinkle materials. Setting them to Zero gives the desired result

Metallic and Specular Tint both add color to the Glossy Direct Pass.

[image: Principled BSDF]

[image: Result]

If you do need the metallic value, you can also use a Hue Saturation Value Node in the compositor and set the saturation to 0 to get a greyscale image.

[image: Compositing]

Comment: Thank you!
However, the operation of this node is not identical to the glory direct pass.
Apparently, author of the tutorial wanted to get a some different effect, not desaturate.
Therefore, if want to apply a metallic value - I would like to ask the author of the tutorial - what to do in this case.
[compare screenshot](https://i2.paste.pics/85dc850e6fd395573e1296c92bb81ee8.png)
Thanks!